# how to fetch data from existing remote oracle database on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I have already installed the required oci8 gem as well as instant client connection was successful 
however i still can't retrieve the data from the existing table from the database such as there is a userlists table

I have tried to use scaffold without a migration to create the application but oracle has given me the error saying

```
OCIError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

**Below is my database.yml setup**

```rb
default: &default
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: link to server
  database: dbname
  username: dbuser
  password: dbpass
  port: portnum

development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  username: dbuser
  password: dbpass
  database: serverlink/dbname
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error is about `schema_migrations` table (contains one varchar column `version`), which rails uses to store info about which migrations have been applied to the database.

If you can change the database - the simplest way is to create that table, as you might need that later.

Also you can try setting `config.active_record.migration_error = false`